# iPhone carrier provisioning

Tags: ios, iphone, memory

I upgraded a VZN iPhone 4's IOS version and noticed that it configured itself for VZN.  I think that IOS examines information on the phone (someplace in memory) to determine which carrier it should provision the phone with.

If this is the case,

1. Is the carrier ID memory location a "known quantity"?
2. How to access the addressable memory space and view this memory location?

If you have performed 2, please state this in your response.  Ideally, there would be a good step-by-step procedure to perform the view memory exercise

Comment: Please clarify if this is an iPhone 4 or an iPhone 4s since the 4 doesn't have a Sim Card vs. the 4s does and that might be your answer - it's hard from your question to determine since you wrote "4's"

Comment: Good question: it is a 4S and has a SIM card.

Comment: Then that's most likely the answer to your question as the phone is taking that information from the Sim Card, try inserting a different Sim Card and that should take care on this under normal circumstances

Comment: Clarification: The observation was that when upgrading IOS (no SIM card engaged), the phone configured itself per Verizon provisioning policy.